# Create database without logging in to cpanel

Tags: php, mysql

I am keeping a separate database for each client in my web-app. But that would mean having root access every time a new client is added. 
I have a vps server for hosting. 
My question is, is it possible to create databases using code and not through the cpanel? If not, is there any other way to do this without having to login to cpanel every time? What are my options here?

Comment: I don't know how many clients you expect to have, but using 1 database and adding a client ID to some of the tables probably scales a lot better.

Comment: Yes, I considered that option. But separate databases was what would work better, even with the limitation of creating databases only with cpanel. Now I am hoping to find a workaround for that

Comment: There is no such thing as a "phpmyadmin database"

Comment: @Dagon Yes, sorry. I meant the mysql database you create using the phpmyadmin gui. I just edited. Apologies.
Any suggestions on the problem, though?

Comment: Phpmyadmin has nothing to do with it. There are several valid answers below

Answer (score 0):

You can create db using coding.The following create database named 'myDB':

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// Create database
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE myDB";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Database created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**create database**

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Create database
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE myDB";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Database created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

**crate table**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```